# Haskell - overloading number types

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, overloading

I have a simple function defined below:

```
allZero :: Num a => [a]-> Bool
allZero [] = False
allZero xs = and (map (== 0) xs)
```

This returns an error message upon loading:

> *Could not deduce (Num a) arising from the literal `0'*

What is the problem with this function? How do I oveload the number 0 to be of any numeric type a?

Comment: Because the place of `Num` in the type-class hierarchy changed (a while ago), it may be worth specifying which version of GHC you're using.

Comment: By the way, I would expect `allZero []` to return true. You can also use `all (==0) xs` instead of `and (map (==0) xs)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code compiles once you add an `Eq a` constraint to `allZero`. There should be no other issues compiling this code.

```
allZero :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a]-> Bool
allZero [] = False
allZero xs = and (map (== 0) xs)
```

As some commenters pointed out, the first case is non-standard, as `allZero` of `[]` is typically `True`. With that definition, the first case becomes redundant.

Comment: It seems that I was learning from an outdated book, thank you!